# Likelihood of the Mixture of "Binomial" Distributions

Tags: binomial-distribution, likelihood, mixture-distribution

I have 2 models. One is mixture of binomials with $p_1=1/3$ and $p_2=2/3$, second - mixture with $p_3=1/4, p_4=2/4, p_5=3/4$. Priors are equal and uniform inside each model and between models.

The question is: for a data point (a,b) say which model is more likely for this data.

It is worth to mention that the data points are not "$a$ successes, $b$ failures",they are "$a$ or $b$ of successes, $b$ or $a$ failures" - it is like we made $n$ coin tosses but then forgot which ones were heads and which ones were tails. For simplicity, I suggest to think that $a \leq b$, but we do not know if $a$ or $b$ successes happened.

So let's imagine that we have a data point $(a,b), a \leq b$ and we do not know whether $a$ means the number of successes or failures, size of "Binomial" = a + b, that means a + b coin tosses happened. How can I estimate the first model's likelihood having this data point?

Any hints are welcome - I started to derive the likelihood by myself but then smth went wrong and now I doubt my results. How can I write the pmf of this RV?

Comment: I do not think that the pmf of your event "a or b successes" is binomial. It is the sum of two binomial probabilities $P(a; n, p) + P(b;n, p)$.

Comment: @tomka but if I want to calculate likelihood - should I just multiply each P by 0.5 and then sum? Because another model, $M_2$, has more potential $p$s and also should be multiplied (by ⅓ I guess) so they will become comparable in the end..

Comment: You need to make an assumption on the distribution of the random flip between successes and failures.